# Multi module project - redundant pom.xml

Tags: maven

I have a project with a structure similar to the following:

```
project-root
|--pom.xml (parent pom)
   |--moduleA
      |--pom.xml (redundant?)
      |--moduleA1
         |--pom.xml
      |--moduleA2
         |--pom.xml
   |--moduleB
      |--pom.xml
```

Look at the POM file at root of `moduleA`. It is simply there to link `moduleA1` and `moduleA2` to the parent pom.

Using this configuration, in the parent pom I will reference the module `moduleA` only and use the possibly redundant module to link the sub modules.

Question :: Is it acceptable to remove this redundant pom and then link the modules in the parent pom as follows, or does it break convention

```
<module>moduleA/moduleA1</module>
<module>moduleA/moduleA2</module>
```

The reason for this is that I find it quite annoying to have a bunch of these "link type poms" installed in my repository.

Thank you

Comment: I do it like that. But is it against the convention? idk

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is of course acceptable assuming you set `<parent><relativePath>../..</relativePath></parent>` for your `moduleA1` and `moduleA2`, so they are link do their parent on the filesystem level (and not only by Maven repository).

I don't see any strong reason against your idea, but it's quite uncommon.

Comment: I think I will leave it as is - I don't want to break the norm and confuse people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the opinion they are redundant why are not removing the level.

You currently have:

```
project-root
|--pom.xml (parent pom)
   |--moduleA
      |--pom.xml (redundant?)
      |--moduleA1
         |--pom.xml
      |--moduleA2
         |--pom.xml
   |--moduleB
      |--pom.xml
```

so why not changing your structure into this:

```
project-root
|--pom.xml (parent pom)
    |--moduleA1
        |--pom.xml
    |--moduleA2
        |--pom.xml
   |--moduleB
      |--pom.xml
```

Usually the intermediate levels have the idea to define common things in the "redundant" pom file special plugins configurations which are only valid for moduleA1 and moduleA2 etc. If you don't have such things it does not make sense to make a intermediate level.

Comment: Well, the sub levels are logically linked and it would be messy to have them all at a common higher level. Think SDK + Examples. I agree that the "redundant" pom is useful for common config - even if empty now it allows for future flexibility. I will leave it as is. Thanks.